# reorder grouped bars within sns.catplot

Tags: python, graph, seaborn

I'm trying to reorder the bars within my sns.catplot (seaborn), but my bars are grouped. I was able to reorder the groups of bars (e.g., A, B, and C) but have not been able to reorder the bars within the groups.

Currently, you can see my bars within each group follow an orange-green, orange-green, orange-green pattern.

[image: current image]

Current code: (#FF5720 is orange, #18C288 is green)

```
sns.catplot(data = data, 
            x = x,
            y = y,
            hue='condition',
            kind='bar', 
            order=['A', 'B', 'C'],
            palette=sns.color_palette(['#FF5720', '#18C288']))
```

However, I'd like to reverse this to green-orange, green-orange, green-orange. Does any one have advice?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`hue_order=`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) parameter:

```
sns.catplot(data = data, 
            x = x,
            y = y,
            hue='condition',
            kind='bar', 
            order=['A', 'B', 'C'],
            hue_order=['green','orange'],
            palette=sns.color_palette(['#FF5720', '#18C288']))
```